# Looping through a CFArray of CFURL

Tags: swift, core-services

Using Swift, I'm trying to loop through a CFArray of CFURLs but I'm getting a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error.

```swift
let apps = LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.yahoo.com")! as CFURL, LSRolesMask.all)!

let finalArray = apps.takeRetainedValue()

let count = CFArrayGetCount(finalArray)

for ix in 0...count-1 {
    let url = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(finalArray, ix) as! CFURL
    print(url)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really want to stay in the abyss of CoreFoundation?  Cast the array to `[URL]`

```
if let apps = LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(URL(string: "http://www.yahoo.com")! as CFURL, LSRolesMask.all)?.takeRetainedValue() {
    for url in apps as! [URL] {
        print(url)
    }
}
```

By the way the error occurs because `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex` returns a pointer which cannot be cast to `CFURL`

You would have to write something like

```
for ix in 0..<count {
    let url = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(finalArray, ix), to: URL.self)
    print(url)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing how to properly cast the array to [URL], that looks way better.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to do:

```
let urls = cfArr as? Array<URL>
```

sample:

```
if let retainedArr = LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/uks/Desktop/taopixie4.png") as CFURL, .all)?.takeRetainedValue(),

let listOfRelatedApps = retainedArr as? Array<URL>
```